# How do I split "a=1,b=2" into a hash in perl?

Tags: perl

I want to do this:

```
my %options = makeHash("user=bob,pass=123");
```

Bonus points if anyone can make this work...

```
my %options = makeHash('user="bob,a",pass=123');
```

I can easily write the first method with multiple split()'s but I want to know if there is a cool elegant way specific to Perl this can be done...

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble? Right now, your question reads like "please write this code for me."

Comment: smells like `cvs` or something similar

Comment: @loldop Concurrent Versions Systems? :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Text::ParseWords`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aParseWords) (a core module in Perl 5) parse the fields, and also overcome quoted comma signs inside the fields. Note that the return value is a hash reference, not a hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $options = makeHash('user="bob,a",pass=123');

sub makeHash {
    my $str  = shift;
    my @foo  = quotewords(',', 0, $str);   # split into pairs
    my %hash = quotewords('=', 0, @foo);   # split into key + value
    return \%hash;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your keys and values are all alphanumeric then you can just write

```
my %options = "user=bob,pass=123" =~ /\w+/g;
```

or, for your second case

```
my %options = 'user="bob,a",pass=123' =~ /(\w+)="?([\w,]+)/g;
```

You need to be clear exactly what characters can appear in your data, whether or not there may be spaces around the `=` etc.